# Cutting down on react-redux action code, is this a bad solution?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have my actions setup like so to update my store.

```
export const updateUser = (data) => {
    return{
        type: 'UPDATE_USER',
        payload: data
    };
};

const initialState = {
    email: null,
    name: null
};


export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_USER':
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
            break;
        default: return state;
    }
}

updateUser({ email: 'new email', name: 'some guys name'});
```

Is this a viable solution to update my store, or should I make my actions more specific, I am not really enjoying the amount of code redux adds to my projects.

Comment: You don't need `break` immediately after `return`. This should reduce the amount of code a little :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic definition of a redux action is `{ type: 'type', payload: 'payload' }`, so your action creator is fine.

You can actually create an actions creator creator like this:

```
const actionsCreatorCreator = (type) => (payload) => ({
  type,
  payload
});

//and create many actions from it

export const updateUser = actionsCreatorCreator('UPDATE_USER');
export const addUser = actionsCreatorCreator('ADD_USER');
```

You can also use an actions / reducers utility library that provides methods to create actions, and reducers. I've used [redux-actions](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-actions) in the past.

These are other small optimizations I've adopted to reduce the amount of actions/reducers code.

**Note** - using object rest/spread required Babel's [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

```
export const updateUser = (payload) => ({ // return the object without a return statement
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload // shorthand property name
});

const initialState = {
    email: null,
    name: null
};    

export default function(state = initialState, { type, payload }) { // destructure the action
    switch(type) {
        case 'UPDATE_USER':
            return { ...state, ...payload } // use object rest/spread instead of assign
    }

    return state; // return after the switch instead of default
}

updateUser({ email: 'new email', name: 'some guys name'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information mate I will use this advice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is asking about having an `UPDATE_USER` action that can return any fields, vs having separate `UPDATE_USER_NAME` and `UPDATE_USER_EMAIL` actions.  Yes, that's absolutely fine - you definitely do not *have* to define separate action types for every field in a form.

The naming and intent of your actions is up to you - do whatever you find works best for your situation and makes your code maintainable and easier to understand.

I did write some related thoughts on action semantics in my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/), which you might want to read through.